# Getting error while clone the gitrepo using ssh-key

Tags: github, ssh-keys, git-clone, ssh-keygen, git-repo

I have created a public key after  I have pasted it on GitHub then I have tried to do `git clone`.

But while doing the clone, it is asking for the password:

[image: error]

Did i do anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have pasted your SSH public key in your User SSH setting page of your *local* GitHub instance, not `github.com`.

Second, test if you are correctly authenticated with:

```
ssh -Tv git@stg-...github-....local
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            your local GitHub server name
```

You should see which key is used, and if yours is selected.

Comment: i tried this but i am still getting the same error. 
debug1: Trying private key: /home/machkuri.rathan-a/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive
Password:

Comment: @VikasRathan Getting the same error is expected. The goal was to check what key was served. In your case, a non-default key `id_xmss` is used, which means you must have a `~/.ssh/config` file which explicitly reference this key. DId you register `id_xmss.pub` in your GitHub Enterprise on-premise instance? (the `stg-...github-....local` one)

Comment: yes, we have the config file but there is  no id_xmss key , how can we create it ?

Comment: @VikasRathan `ssh-keygen -P "" -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_xmss`. Register the `id_xmss.pub` and try again.

Comment: debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Server not found in Kerberos database.    its still asking the password,   i have created  id_xmss key and pasted the pub one on github.

Comment: @VikasRathan This time, you do have `/home/machkuri.rathan-a/.ssh/id_xmss`? And registerd the `id_xmss.pub`? Are you on Windows?

Comment: yes, i am on windows, i have the id_xmss.pub key and i have configured it on github.                               -rw-------. 1 machkuri.rathan-a domain users  2643 Feb 13 18:37 id_xmss
-rw-r--r--. 1 machkuri.rathan-a domain users   601 Feb 13 18:37 id_xmss.pub .  do i need to chnage any permission to the key ?

Comment: @VikasRathan permissions look good. This is more a DNS issue when trying to access your GHE server `stg-...github-....local`, as [illustrated in this (unrelated) issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-kerberos/issues/134#issuecomment-536213319).

Comment: Not sure i have raised the support ticket to Github also.